# How to adjust a card image with React and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I understand that this might be a newbie inquiry, but I am not really good at CSS, so I would appreciate some tips on how to achieve my objective.

I am trying to create a card album for NFT similar to the image below:

[image: Goal]

Instead what I get with my code is the image displaying over the Title, Description, Price, and Button. How can this be fixed?

**JSX File:**

```
return (
    <>
      <div className="img-grid">
        {nfts.map((nft, i) => (
          <div key={i} className="img-wrap">
            <img src={nft.image} />
            <div>
              <p>{nft.name}</p>
              <div>{nft.description}</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <p>{nft.price}</p>
              <button onClick={() => buyNft(nft)}>buy</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

**CSS file:**

```
.img-grid {
  /* width: 80%; */
  margin: 1px auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 50px;
}

.img-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  padding: 50% 0;
  /* padding controls height, will always be perfectly square regardless of width */
  position: relative;
  /* opacity: 0.8; */
}

.img-wrap img {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 150%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

**What I achieved:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to put the image wrapper and paragraph separately

```html
<div className="img-grid">
  {nfts.map((nft, i) => (
    <div key={i}>
      <div className="img-wrap">
        <img src={nft.image} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>{nft.name}</p>
        <div>{nft.description}</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>{nft.price}</p>
        <button onClick={() => buyNft(nft)}>buy</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```